# Trouble with acronyms first used in longtable

Tags: longtable, acro

I am using the acro package. I use some acronyms several times in a longtable and I have them defined with \acs. The thing is that, when those acronyms appear in the text for the first time, the short form is always displayed thus they never get to be defined in the text, conversely to what happens in a regular table. How can I solve this?

Thank you!

[image]

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{report}

 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{acro}

 \DeclareAcronym{acro1}{
 short = ACRO1,
 long  = acronym1,
 tag   = abbrev
 }
 \DeclareAcronym{acro2}{
 short = ACRO2,
 long  = acronym2,
 }
 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h!tbp]
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
          example
          & \acs{acro1} \\
      \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

 First use of acronym in text: \ac{acro1}. Desired behavior!

 \begin{longtable}{ll}
      example
      & \acs{acro2} \\
 \end{longtable}

 First use of acronym in text: \ac{acro2}. :(

 \end{document}
```

Comment: @cgnieder, then write an answer. Your vote you can simply withdraw: click on close and then on "retract".

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, your solution totally worked, thank you! I will accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the starred version `\acs*` inside the `longtable`. The starred commands don't count as usage for `acro` so the `\ac` outside then correctly shows the full form.

The reason this is not necessary inside of a table is that `acro` patches floats to make its command inside of floats as if they were starred.